# How can a slowed light ray bend?

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction

If light is traveling through air, it slows down and ends up bending. But how? If I'm running straight, and I get slowed down, shouldn't I still be running straight?

Comment: This link gives a good explanation, imo : http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/refrn/Lesson-1/The-Direction-of-Bending  also, related to your question, you could look for posts on this site regarding mirages, I haven't looked but I would imagine there are questions similar to yours.

Comment: A reminder that comments are for requesting clarification and suggesting improvements. I've deleted some comments that didn't serve that purpose.

Answer (score 22):

When you say light bends I assume you are talking about [refraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refraction) i.e. the change in the angle of the light given by [Snell's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law).

You ask:

> If I'm running straight, and I get slowed down, shouldn't I still be running straight?

but suppose one foot get slowed down while the other one didn't. In that case you would turn in the direction of the foot that was slowed down. This is analogous to (though not exactly the same as) what happens when light is refracted. If light hits a refractive index boundary head on, i.e. $i = r = 0$, then it is not bent. The change in the angle occurs when the light hits a refractive index boundary at an angle greater than 0, so one side of the wavefront is slowed down first.

Comment: +1 so it's the change of density in the atmosphere, bending light?

Comment: That plus the most-of-the-time non-orthogonal direction in which the light arrives w.r.t. the density gradient.

Answer (score 14):

To augment Rennie's answer with a graphical representation let me post this diagram:

Imagine, if you will, not a single beam of light but a series of wavefronts. When part of the wavefront slows due to a different density, the wavelength also compresses, thus introducing the characteristic bend.

[image]

Comment: the elementary physics book I read way back when explained it as a bunch of people running side-by-side on hard ground when they reach the edge of a sandy beach and keep running (but slower). One end of the line reaches the sand and slows down sooner, while the other end reaches it later and goes fast for longer. Once they're all in the sand, they're still in a straight line, but the line is pointed in a different direction than it was before.

Comment: Okay so I think I get why light refracts, but could you clarify how Fermat's and Huygens's principle  the refraction?

Comment: @mohabdi This is how those principles were originally derived. You can find that in any explanation of the respective principles - this is still high-school-level physics. What is it exactly that you don't understand?

Comment: For example, the statement" the plane light wave propagates though free space at the speed of light, c". What is a "plane" light wave?

Comment: Why does the wavefront stay together like this, instead of doing something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/Wr32yP9.png)? That's certainly what the people in @hobbs' analogy would have done.

Comment: @Random832, that is basically the same diagram as far as the wavefronts go, except the red arrow isn't drawn in the best way. It's not perpendicular to the wavefronts and so it's not a true representation of the new direction. Realign the red arrow with the new wavefronts.

Comment: No, my diagram illustrates a hypothetical situation in which each photon continues in the same direction it originally was moving, contrary to how they actually behave. What is the physical cause of the wave propagating perpendicular to the wavefronts rather than the wavefronts being skewed relative to the propagation direction

Comment: Also I understand the "wavefronts" in both diagrams to be the envelope of the positions of photons that left the source at the same time. They're not always planar (for a point source they're spherical), and they certainly don't correspond to physical waves since this is not coherent light.

Comment: @Random832, when the light is *not* coherent, it is composed of different wavelengths and each wavelength will *bend* at a different amount. This is because of the wave nature of light. I don't believe this behaviour can be explained in terms of photon particles and that is part of the importance of the dual nature of light as both particles and waves. If you are trying to explain it by ignoring its wave nature, you may very well be at a loss.

Comment: @Octopus Light can be monochromatic without being coherent. I just don't understand how each photon "knows" that the rest of the surface is at an angle.

Comment: @Random832 that's a good question and unfortunately it's beyond my ability to explain well, except that it falls out of the principle of least action in a quantum sense. Maybe it can be turned into another question here?